# TFS 2018 Accidental Deletion of WIKI pages

Tags: team-foundation-server, wiki

Spent some time creating a hierarchy of pages off a primary Homepage in the new TFS 2018 Wiki.

I noticed after a while that a second Homepage had appeared so I deleted the duplicate. But as it turns out it wasn't a duplicate, it was a representation of the same page in the same list and by deleting it, it removed all the pages in the Wiki (ouch).

Revisions for each page would have been stored, but I can't access them because there are no physical pages any more.

Is there a way to restore the deleted pages either through the command line or through the web interface without resorting to a backup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki is stored in source control (either Git or TFVC), the appropriate revert (git)/rollback (tfvc) from the Source Control Explorer or the Git Branches view should bring back the deleted data.

Nothing is completely lost. You may want to talk to a developer who is used to source control to help you.